# Proof of Proposition 0.17 in Folland wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Proposition 0.17 in Folland's *Real Analysis* (2e) is

> If $X$ and $Y$ are well ordered, then either X is order isomorphic to
>   $Y$, or $X$ is order isomorphic to an initial segment in $Y$, or $Y$
>   is order isomorphic to an initial segment in $X$.

The proof begins as follows

> Consider the set $\mathscr{F}$ of order isomorphisms whose domains are
>   initial segments in $X$ or $X$ itself and whose ranges are initial
>   segments in $Y$ or $Y$ itself. $\mathscr{F}$ is non-empty since the
>   unique $f \colon \{\inf X\} \to \{\inf Y\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}$,
>   $\ldots$

Here $\inf X$ denotes the minimal element of $X$. My question is whether it is correct to say that $\{\inf X\}$ is an initial segement.

Folland earlier defines an initial segment as the set

> $$I_x = \{y \in X \colon y<x\}$$

for some $x \in X$.

It is not clear to me why there should be an $x \in X$ for which $I_x=\{\inf X\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U=\{\,y\in X\mid \inf X<y\,\}$. If $U$ is empty, then $\{\inf X\}=X$; otherwise let $x=\inf U$ and we have $I_x=\{\inf X\}$.
So you are right: We'd need to distinguzish the special case that $X$ (or $Y$) is a singleton. To repair that, I'd suggest to notice that $\operatorname{id}\colon\emptyset\to \emptyset$ is in $\mathscr F$ as base case (where $\emptyset =I_{\inf X}$ and $\emptyset=I_{\inf Y}$ are initital segments if $X,Y$ are not empty).

Actually, we already need to make a distiction for the case of $X$ (or $Y$) being empty (and not having an infimum), but that is straightforward.

Comment: Note that in lots of places the empty set is not a partially ordered set. If you are not going to deal with ordinals, then it is sometimes better to just go with it.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a non-empty well-ordered set, then every non-maximal element $x$ has an immediate successor, $\inf\{y\in X\mid x<y\}$.

Therefore either $\inf X$ is the maximal element, or it has a successor. In the former case $\{\inf X\}=X$ is an initial segment, otherwise it is the initial segment defined by the successor of $\inf X$.

Comment: Thanks. This is a fact I should have thought of. I wish I could accept both your and @Hagen's answer, but am forced to choose.

Comment: It's more than fine. Hagen's answer is very good.